# FileStream/StreamWriter if another user has the file open

Tags: c#, io, streamwriter

I am writing data to a log file as users submit information.  Other users within the office may need to view this log file but I cannot continue writing to the log file as more inforation is submitted if the office user has the file open.  Is there a way to continue writing to a file even if another user has an instance of the file open?

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"\\filelocation\filename.csv"))
{
     writer.WriteLine("Testing, testing");

     writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: Yep... Take away Writer.Close()

Comment: I know it is redundant but I was alway taught to put the Close as an added fail safe.  Maybe it's not recommended but it's also got nothing to do with my question.

Comment: I'll have to rephrase that I guess.  Don't close it and don't dispose it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might I suggest using the Trace if you need to continue creating a log file?  You can attach a "listener" to the Trace like this.

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener("myfilename.txt"));
```

Of course if you pass it a filename, it will not autoflush, and nothing will be in the file till it closes, or the buffer fills up.  So you could create the stream at the start of your program.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("myLogFile.txt");
StreamWriter _sw;

void Main()
{
    _sw = fi.CreateText();
    _sw.AutoFlush = true;
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(sw));
}

void Close()
{
    if(_sw != null)
    {
        _sw.Flush();
        _sw.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then in your program, instead of opening and closing a file for each write to a "log" you can instead just do this.

```
Trace.WriteLine("My message here");
```

Trace has a cool thing called categories too, which are great for logs...

```
Trace.WriteLine("My message here", "INFO");

//Output:
//INFO: My message here
```

One thing I have found is that on some systems you cannot open the text file, but you can make a copy of it to open, and the original file will continue to fill.

Comment: This answer is a little over my head but it seems to be the most complete solution offered thus far.  I ended up just creating a separate csv file timestamped with that specific submission so that the streamwriter never tries to write to the same file twice.